# Security / Encrypted bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wan't to create encrypted connection between Android Phone and BLE device. I'm doing bonding process and its working fine.

How to make connection encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the peripheral is configured to distribute its LTK during the pairing phase (See Bluetooth Core 5.0 specification, Vol 3, Part H, section 3.6.1), then Android will store that key and on each subsequent connection attempt automatically encrypt the link.

Comment: For now LTK is not configured. From Android I'm doing createBond() and device.setPin(). But looks like something is missing but don't know yet what.

Comment: After pairing, the link will always encrypted. However encryption should be done on subsequent connections, you have to distribute the LTK. That's the only thing you need to do.